# How do I access Assets folder in WinUI 3 app project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

I am adding some app assets in the `Assets` folder (more specifically, a subfolder in the `Assets` folder) like this:

[image]

How do I access the files in that `Assets` folder from my app's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do.

First is the code. The property you are looking for is: `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledPath`. This will get you to the root of the project. From there, append the file path within the project: `"/Assets/Config/MyFile.txt"` to access a file called `MyFile` in the `Config` subfolder in your image.

An example usage would be:

```
public string LoadFile()
{
    string fullPath = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledPath + "/Assets/Config/MyFile.txt";
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return fileContents;
        }
    }
}
```

If you try to run this, you will run into an error saying part of the path cannot be found. If you check your app's installed location (use the error text to get the location on your system to look), you will find the `Config` folder is in fact missing from the `Assets` folder. **This is because you need to tell the project to copy the folder over to the installed package**.

To do this, modify your project file (`.csproj` - you can double click on the project in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio to get to the XML code). Add the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Assets\Config\MyFile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

[RegEx do appear to work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/888091/how-to-include-an-34assets34-folder-in-a-winui3-ms.html) in the `Update` property, so you could try something like `"Assets\Config\*"` to have all contents of the `Config` subfolder copied over rather than the single file.

Comment: Hi Michael Kintscher they-them, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: What about unpackaged apps?